# Robust way to compute significance between counts without standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, z-score

I'm a little rusty, but without information on standard deviation, and simply using the counts themselves, one can compute some basic significance which I know as a rule of thumb as simply the difference between the counts divided by the square root of the sum of those counts. Providing for example we split A/B with equal probability and then count the number in each category $a$ and $b$ that then gives us the z-score used to determine a p-value.

$$z = \frac{(a- b)}{ \sqrt{a + b}}$$

My question is therefore, how robust is this? Let me qualify. There is a split, and two models are applied A and B. Each of those model responses is counted for *specific* events and are effectively the counts $a$ and $b$. In terms of the question, is there a difference between these counts due to the models A/B?

Comment: Robust against what assumption? I hope "[W]e split A/B with equal probability." means equal nrs of subjects were _randomly_ assigned to gps A and B (maybe 50 each). And then that you got $a$ successes in gp A and $b$ successes in gp B (maybe $a=13, b=26.$ Without random assignment, all is lost. // But maybe you mean 'power'. Then in R `prop.test(c(13, 26), c(50,50))` returns P-value 0.01388 which is significant at 5% level. [But $a=13, b= 21$ is not signficant.] With 50 in each group, you have good enough _power_ to distinguish btw sample proportions .26 & .52, but not btw .26 and .42.

Comment: This is a valid Z-score for Poisson-distributed counts and (therefore) referring it to the standard Normal distribution (or, better, Student t) to assess significance will be a pretty good approximation provided neither count is too small. "Not small" could be, say, anything $10$ or greater, depending on your tolerance for error. In the $(13,26)$ example by @Bruce, $Z=2.08$ and a two-sided test of equality has an approximate p-value of $0.037.$ This exceeds Bruce's number because no assumption has been made about sample sizes. With much larger sample sizes, `prop.test` will give $p=0.055.$